# How to use hash function to avoid duplicate point in a line?

Tags: c++11, hash

Lets say I have a vector of points. Now I want to use these points to create a line. But during this line creation, there might be some duplicate points that I want to avoid. To avoid duplicates, I used unordered_map and its hash function. Every thing was fine until I encountered `1.10` and `1.10000001` (I want to assume these two numbers are equal).

So I thought this was because of `return ((x == other.x) && (y == other.y) && (z == other.z));` and I changed it to make sure that decimal with in 0.0004 range of difference are equal. But this also did not changed the result.

My two questions are

1) Is there a way where I can tell my hash function to treat ***nearly equal*** decimal as ***equal***.

2)  I have read that decimals are poor choice for hash function but, is there any alternative to avoid duplicate decimal points in my `paint_line`.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct vec3{
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;

  bool operator==(const vec3& other) const {
   // return ((x == other.x) && (y == other.y) && (z == other.z));
    return (std::fabs(x - other.x) < 1e-4) && 
           (std::fabs(y - other.y) < 1e-4) &&
           (std::fabs(z- other.z) < 1e-4);
  }
};


struct Vec3Hasher {
  size_t operator()(const vec3& k) const {
    size_t h1 = std::hash<double>()(k.x);
    size_t h2 = std::hash<double>()(k.y);
    size_t h3 = std::hash<double>()(k.z);
    return (h1 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ h3;
  }
};

int main(){     
  std::vector<vec3> line;  

  line.push_back({1.10,2.0,0.0});
  line.push_back({1.10,2.0,0.0});
  line.push_back({2.10,2.0,0.0});
  line.push_back({1.10000001,2.0,0.0});
  line.push_back({1.10,2.0,0.0});

  std::unordered_map<vec3, int, Vec3Hasher> paint_line;
  paint_line.clear();

  int count = 0;
  for(const auto& it : line){

    std::cout.precision(7); 

    auto rval_it = paint_line.find(it);

    if(rval_it == paint_line.end()){
      std::cout << "its new val " << std::endl;
      paint_line.insert(std::make_pair(it, count++));          
    }else{
      std::cout <<std::fixed << "its duplicate   : "<< "("<< rval_it->first.x << "," 
                << rval_it->first.y << "," << rval_it->first.z <<")" << std::endl; 

    }

  }

}
```

> its new val
>
> its duplicate   : (1.1,2,0)
>
> its new val
>
> **its new val   ( I was expecting this also to be duplicate (1.10000001)**
>
> its duplicate   : (1.1,2,0)

Comment: would it be acceptable to use a fixed-point approximation for the hash?  i.e., for `double x`, use `std::hash<long long>((long long)(x * 10000))` to keep 4 decimal places?

Comment: Yes that worked. So basically instead of using all the number from decimal (each and every number before and after decimal) we end up using all the numbers before decimal and four numbers after decimal (which is effectively done by multiplying the decimal by 10000 and converting it to `long long` or `size_t`) .

Comment: Yep, that's the idea.  You do have to be a bit careful that `double` can be much larger than `long long` can handle, but in your program, it might be okay.  Only you can answer that.

Comment: I guess the question is what are the units of your coordinate system? pixels or whole screens, or inches, or something else? This will help you decide how visible the effect of rounding will be, and how much rounding you can get away with. For example, in pixels, a line drawn to an endpoint at 0.1 pixel accuracy will be fine, but that is ~0.0001 screens, and ~0.00002 inches on a 600dpi laser printer.